# Excelscript (online) getting the userid that updates the workbook

Tags: office-scripts

I have a shared workbook that can be updated by different people. My excelscript online gets the last user who updated the workbook with this code:

```
  // Get the document properties.
  const properties: ExcelScript.DocumentProperties = workbook.getProperties();
  // Get Author
  let Author = properties.getLastAuthor();
```

My script also updates the workbook data but, after the updates, is not able to retrieve the name of active user who is running the script (and updating automatically the data)

I have tried some code to give time to the script retriving the correct name but it always gets the previous name not the actual one. The code I used:

```
  const application = workbook.getApplication();
  application.calculate(ExcelScript.CalculationType.fullRebuild);
  let subject1 = "Entrevista anual 2023 firmada en " + currentDateTime;
  console.log(subject1);
```

Any idea about retriving the name of the user who is running the script?

Comment: Did you try to get it with `getAuthor()`?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.documentproperties?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461

Comment: I try getAuthor() but the result is the original person who created the workbook, not the actual one that is updating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround is to add and then delete a comment, e.g:

```
let c = selectedSheet.addComment("K1", "working");
console.log(c.getAuthorName());
c.delete();
```

Only email and name are available though, not the userid.